# Processing C# Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help in cleaning up a collection in C# (performance is also a concern)

Here how my collection is organized

```
List<EZA> ezaCollection = new List<EZA>() {
    new EZA() {
        someDate = "2018-03-24",
        PZA = new List < PZA > () {
            new PZA {
                name = 'inter_1'
            },
            new PZA {
                name = 'inter_2'
            },
        }
    },
    new EZA() {
        someDate = "2018-04-24",
        PZA = new List < PZA > () {
            new PZA {
                name = 'inter_2'
            },
            new PZA {
                name = 'inter_3'
            },
        }
    }
}
```

What I need help with to generate copy of this collection using Linq where duplicate name under PZA only remain in the collection with highest someDate?

Any Suggestions?

This is what i am expected to generate as final list where inter_2 from the fist EZA is removed coz it was present in the second list with a higher someDate

```
 new List<EZA>() {
        new EZA() {
            someDate = "2018-03-24",
            PZA = new List < PZA > () {
                new PZA {
                    name = 'inter_1'
                }              
            }
        },
        new EZA() {
            someDate = "2018-04-24",
            PZA = new List < PZA > () {
                new PZA {
                    name = 'inter_2'
                },
                new PZA {
                    name = 'inter_3'
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your complete code and what results it gives

Comment: Is there a reason why your problem must be solved with LINQ?

Comment: Try following : var results = ezaCollection.Select(x => x.PZA.Where(name => name.name != "inter_2").ToList()).ToList();

Comment: @CallumWatkins I have some subsequent select queries that follow the intial fileter..we are trying to avoid changing all that code

Comment: @fireholster Provided memory isn't an issue, you can still perform select queries on a data structure afterwards

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure what you are suggesting here

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you updates.  Try code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<EZA> ezaCollection = new List<EZA>() {
                new EZA() {
                    someDate = "2018-03-24",
                    PZA = new List < PZA > () {
                        new PZA {
                            name = "inter_1"
                        },
                        new PZA {
                            name = "inter_2"
                        },
                    }
                },
                new EZA() {
                    someDate = "2018-04-24",
                    PZA = new List <PZA> () {
                        new PZA {
                            name = "inter_2"
                        },
                        new PZA {
                            name = "inter_3"
                        },
                    }
                }
            };

            var names = ezaCollection.Select(eza => eza.PZA.Select(y => new { date = eza.someDate, PZA = eza.PZA, pza = y, Name = y.name })).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

            var groups = names.OrderByDescending(x => x.date).GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList();


            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                foreach (var item in group.Skip(1))  //skip latest
                {
                    item.PZA.Remove(item.pza);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class EZA
    {
        public string name { get; set;}
        public string someDate { get; set; }
        public List<PZA> PZA { get; set;}
    }
    public class PZA
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `PZA` may end up in a branch below the one where you first spot it, you need to make two passes through your lists - one to associate `PZA` with the latest `EZA`, and one more to make the actual copy.

The first pass would go like this:

```
var pzaForEzaDate = ezaCollection.SelectMany(e => e.PZA.Select(p => new {
    Pza = p, Date = e.SomeDate // Associate EZA's date with each PZA
})).GroupBy(t => t.Pza.Name)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Date).Max());
```

The above dictionary contains the latest `EZA` date for each `PZA` name. With this dictionary in place you can walk the original list again, and attach `PZA`s only to `EZA`s from the above `pzaForEzaDate` dictionary:

```
var copy = ezaCollection.Select(e => new EZA {
    SomeDate= e.SomeDate
,   PZA = e.PZA.Where(p => e.SomeDate == pzaForEzaDate[p.Name]).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fit to your solution:

```
var result = ezaCollection 
.SelectMany(d => d.PZA, (eza, pza) => new { EZA = eza, PZA = pza })
.OrderByDescending(u => u.EZA.someDate)
.GroupBy( u => u.PZA.name)
.Select( u => u.First())
.GroupBy(u => u.EZA)
.Select(u => new EZA {
      someDate = u.Key.someDate,
      PZA = u.Select(p => p.PZA).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

[Test code in dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7BRJW1)